# Deciding whether $\sum (a_n - a_{n+1})$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I am having trouble figuring out the following problem.

> Let $(a_n)$ be a real Cauchy sequence. Decide whether $\sum (a_n - a_{n+1})$ converges.

My instinct is no. Because $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, it converges to $L$, but if $L \neq 0$, there is no guarantee that $(a_n - a_{n+1}) \to 0$.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Hint: compute and simplify the partial sums of the series.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $S_{n-1} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (a_k - a_{k+1})= a_1-a_n\to a_1 - L$. Thus the series converges to $a_1 - L$, $L = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ since it is Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, what is the definition of a Cauchy sequence? In the real numbers yes they do converge, but that isn't actually the definition. Its important to know the difference between a convergent sequence and a cauchy sequence.

Now lets see what the partial sums look like.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N(a_n - a_{n+1}) 
&= a_1 - a_2 + a_2 - a_3 + ... + a_{N-1} - a_{N} + a_{N} - a_{N-1}\\
&=a_1-a_{N-1}
\end{align*}
If these are the partial sums, does this series converge?